# How to generate c# classes using XML and XSD

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML that I want to create C# classes with. I can make them with Visual Studio and Edit / Paste Special / Paste XML As Classes, but with that, I have a problem with datatypes.

Now, I have all XSDs for namespaces that XML is using, so my question is there a way to generate C# classes using those XSDs as well?

Comment: You can use the XML Schema Definition Tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe

Comment: Thanks, but the tool is not properly documented, I have 14 files that together exceed 260 characters in a file name, so I have to struggle to find a solution: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ab41df8-69d4-44e4-8795-436088f230e2/xsdexe-path-is-too-long-after-being-fully-qualified?forum=xmlandnetfx